# Java - Communication between classes - issue

Tags: java, class, communication, clock

I´m making an analogue clock and I´ve got a problem I cannot solve.

I´ve got three classes: main, clock, pointer.
Main just creates the clock and starts everything.
Clock manages how the clock works and paints it.
Pointer defines what the pointers do.

The clock creates three pointers with different images and speed.
In the pointer-class a timer is started with the argument speed.

Depending on the speed (i.e. what pointer it is) the pointers angle will increase.
The clock gets the angle when painting.

My problem is that I can´t get the pointer objects to tell the clock when an action was performed so that it can be updated and repainted? How to solve? I can´t create a new clock object from the pointers since I get tons of errors.

Please help!

Here´s the code: (ignore the cycle() method in clock)

**Main:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {



   public Main(){
      add(new Clock());
      setTitle("Klocka");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(400,400);
      setVisible(true);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(false);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      new Main();
   }
}
```

**Clock:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Clock extends JPanel {




    private Image back;
    private int angle = 1;
    private int a = 1;
    private int b = 0;

    public Pointer pPink;
    public Pointer pWeird;
    public Pointer pRose;







   public Clock(){
       pPink = new Pointer(3600,"pink.jpg");
       pWeird = new Pointer(60,"weird.jpg");
       pRose = new Pointer(1,"rose.jpg");


       }




   public void paint(Graphics g) {
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       if (pPink.img != null){

           g2d.rotate(pPink.angle*(3.1415/180));

           g2d.drawImage(pPink.getImg(), 200 ,60, this);

           }

       if (pWeird.img != null){
           g.drawImage(pWeird.getImg(), 250, 200, null);
           }

       if (pRose.img != null){
           g.drawImage(pRose.getImg(), 300, 200, null);
           }




       ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("wheel.png"));
       back = i.getImage();
       g.drawImage(back,50,50, null);


       g.dispose();
       cycle();

           }

   public void cycle(){  // a terrible try to solve the problem...

       if (angle != pPink.angle){

           repaint();
           System.out.println(angle);
           System.out.println(pPink.angle);
           System.out.println("");
           angle = pPink.angle;


       }

   }
}
```

**Pointer:**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Pointer implements ActionListener {

    public int angle = 0;
    public int speed;
    public String fileName;
    public Image img;
    Timer timer;




   public Pointer(int speed, String fileName) {
      this.speed = speed * 1000 ;
      timer = new Timer(this.speed, this);
      timer.start();

      this.fileName = fileName;
      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(this.fileName));
      img = ii.getImage();



   }


   public Image getImg(){
       return img;

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       angle+= 6;
       System.out.println("angle increased");

   }


}
```

Comment: Where is the Action being generated?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the `Observer` pattern. The `Clock` will be the observer who will observe the `Pointer`s. The `Pointer`s will notify the `Clock` when an action was performed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the clock in the Pointer class:

```
. . . 
private Clock clock;

public Pointer(Clock clock, int speed, String fileName) {
    this.clock = clock;
. . .
```

Then you can invoke repaint on the clock in your actionPerformed method:

```
. . .
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    angle += 6;
    System.out.println("angle increased");
    clock.repaint();
. . .
```

To instance the pointers:

```
. . .
public Clock(){
    pPink = new Pointer(this, 3600, "pink.jpg");
    pWeird = new Pointer(this, 60, "weird.jpg");
    pRose = new Pointer(this, 1, "rose.jpg");
. . .
```